# cocos2d sprite animation

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

How can I change an image position in cocos2d like background-position in css? By position I don't mean the position of background like ccp(200,150), I mean for example, I have an image with resolution of (1000,200) that contains 5 (200,200) images. I show this image in (200,200) sprite and I want to change the image position so I can show 5 pictures in 1 picture. I think If you want to show a movement like running, you use sprites with like 10 frames of movement and change the picture position so it looks like a person is running. How can I do that? 
thanx in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found it :

```
AtlasSpriteManager *mgr = [AtlasSpriteManager spriteManagerWithFile:@"ax.png" capacity:6];
AtlasSprite *sprite = [AtlasSprite spriteWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200) spriteManager:mgr];
[sprite setTransformAnchor:ccp(0,0)];
sprite.position = ccp(100,100);
[mgr addChild:sprite z:0];

// Add manager to this layer
[self addChild:mgr z:3];

// Create animation
AtlasAnimation* animation = [AtlasAnimation animationWithName:@"testAnimation" delay:0.1];
assert( animation != nil );

// Define the frames in the sprite sheet used for the animation
[animation addFrameWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[animation addFrameWithRect:CGRectMake(300, 0, 200, 200)];
[animation addFrameWithRect:CGRectMake(400, 0, 200, 200)];
[animation addFrameWithRect:CGRectMake(500, 0, 200, 200)];
[animation addFrameWithRect:CGRectMake(600, 0, 200, 200)];
[animation addFrameWithRect:CGRectMake(700, 12, 200, 200)];  
id action = [Animate actionWithAnimation:animation]; 
assert( action != nil );

// Run the animation
id repeatAction = [Repeat actionWithAction:action times:100];

// To repeat forever, use this
// id repeatAction = [RepeatForever actionWithAction:action];

[sprite runAction:repeatAction];
```